# What's the difference between "ModulePassManagers", "FunctionPassManager" and "BasicBlockPassManagers" in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

What's the difference between "ModulePassManagers", "FunctionPassManager" and "BasicBlockPassManagers" in LLVM?

And, does "FunctionPassManager" can only be used on "function" type in LLVM-IR?

Answer (score 2):

LLVM IR is subdivided into different units. The different units of LLVM IR are as follows

- Modules
- Functions
- Basic blocks
- Instructions

A module consists of functions that are in turn made up of different basic blocks that contain a sequence of instructions. The different pass managers operate on different levels on LLVM-IR. E.g the difference between them is on what abstraction level they operate.

Some useful links discussing the matter in more detail.

[Passes in LLVM](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2014-04/PDFs/Talks/Passes.pdf)

[About the LLVM pass manager](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2014-10/Slides/Carruth-TheLLVMPassManagerPart2.pdf)